# NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[ToastrService -> ToastrService -> InjectionToken ToastConfig -> InjectionToken ToastConfig]:

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material, angular-standalone-components, ngx-toastr

I am stuck in add ngx-toastr in angular standalone micro-frontend in angualr 16. when i add the ngx-toastr provideToast() in main Module component. Please check the below screenshot:

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuWty.png)

Hello,I am stuck in add ngx-toastr in angular standalone micro-frontend in angualr 16. when i add the ngx-toastr provideToast() in main Module component. Please check the below screenshot:

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuWty.png)

Comment: In app.module.ts file, add ToastrModule.forRoot() in import
imports: [ToastrModule.forRoot()],

Comment: Hi we already put this step in angular microfrontend  but it show same error message.

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CommonImportsModule,
    provideToastr(),
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    provideAnimations(),
    StoreModule.forRoot(ROOT_REDUCERS, {
      runtimeChecks: {
        // strictStateImmutability and strictActionImmutability are enabled by default
        strictStateSerializability: true,
        strictActionSerializability: true,
        strictActionWithinNgZone: true,
        strictActionTypeUniqueness: true,
      },
    })
      })

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example for you to reference.

Please go through the [`Getting Started`](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr) on Their github page.

#### Steps I followed.

1. Install toaster `npm install ngx-toastr --save`, install `npm install @angular/animations --save` if needed
2. copy paste the below lines to global styles.scss

scss

```
// regular style toast
@import 'ngx-toastr/toastr';

// bootstrap style toast
// or import a bootstrap 4 alert styled design (SASS ONLY)
// should be after your bootstrap imports, it uses bs4 variables, mixins, functions
@import 'ngx-toastr/toastr-bs4-alert';

// if you'd like to use it without importing all of bootstrap it requires
@import 'bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/mixins';
// bootstrap 4
@import 'ngx-toastr/toastr-bs4-alert';
// boostrap 5
@import 'ngx-toastr/toastr-bs5-alert';
```

---

### or

angular.json

```
add the styles array the toaster css

"styles": [
  "styles.scss",
  "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css" // try adding '../' if you're using angular cli before 6
]
```

3. Add the code for opening the toastr

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { provideToastr } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <button (click)="showSuccess()">
      open toaster
    </button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  showSuccess() {
    this.toastr.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideAnimations(), // required animations providers
    provideToastr(), // Toastr providers
  ],
});
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cvd6no?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=angular.json,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Thanks we already use it for standalone component angular 16. but it show same error.

Comment: @manishjadli check if this same configurations is setup for all `bootstrapApplication` code blocks whereever you are using!